# Call method which takes two methods as argument

Tags: kotlin

When I have a function which takes another function as argument I can call it like this:

```
fun foo(m: String, bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    bar(m)
}

foo("a message") { 
    println("message: $it")
}
```

Is there a way to call it like the way above with one bracket block? I only know this way:

```
fun foo(m: String, bar1: (m: String) -> Unit, bar2: (m: String) -> Unit) {
    bar1(m)
    bar2(m)
}

foo("a message", { println("message 1: $it") }, { println("message 2: $it") } )
```

Comment: you can only move the last function outside of the `()`, i.e. `foo("a message", { println("message 1: $it") })` and then `{ println("message 2: $it") }` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter

Comment: Okay thanks for that! Is there maybe another way to move both functions out? Maybe with an interface or so?

Comment: so you want something like `foo("a message") { println("message 1: $it") } { println("message 2: $it") }`? even if that works, I can not recommend it... it gets harder to see what is just a block and what is a passed function then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the fun of it... here are some tries to get something similar to what you requested. Note that I can not really recommend any other approach then the "standard" one ;-) (that was the disclaimer)

1. standard as is:

   ```
   fun method1(s: String,
               m1: (String) -> String,
               m2: (String) -> String) {
       println(m1(s))
       println(m2(s))
   }
   method1("test", { "m1: $it" }) {
       "m2: $it"
   }
   // if you like with or without mentioning the parameter names:
   method1("test",
       m1 = { "m1: $it" },
       m2 = { "m2: $it" }
   )

   // 1b. using own methods and supplying method references
   fun m1(s : String) = "m1: $s"
   fun m2(s : String) = "m2: $s"
   method1("test1b", ::m1 /*, ::m2 */) {
       "m2: $it"
   }
   ```
2. using invoke...

   ```
   class Method2(val s: String,
                 val m1: (String) -> String) {
       operator fun invoke(m2: (String) -> String) {
           println(m1(s))
           println(m2(s))
       }
   }

   fun method2(s: String,
               m1: (String) -> String) = Method2(s, m1)
   method2("test2") {
       "m1: $it"
   }() {
       "m2: $it"
   }
   ```
3. using a pair supplier with its own ugly extension function

   ```
   fun method3(s: String,
               m1AndM2: () -> Pair<(String) -> String, (String) -> String>) {
       m1AndM2().let { (m1, m2) ->
           println(m1(s))
           println(m2(s))
       }
   }

   infix fun <T : (String) -> String> T.and(m2: (String) -> String) = Pair(this, m2)
   method3("test3") {
       { s: String -> "m1: $s" } and // note: the "s: String" is mandatory as the compiler can not infer the type
           { "m2: $it" }
   }

   // 3b. using a div operator as delimiter (still a hack):
   operator fun <T : (String) -> String> T.div(m2: (String) -> String) = Pair(this, m2)
   method3("test3b") {
       { s: String -> "m1: $s" } / {
           "m2: $it"
       }
   }
   ```

Note: you can even play with one solution or the other and may even come up with something better... Still that was just playing around. I would still stick to the first variant... maybe a method reference is more helpful in your case. I even find the variant with named parameters better then trying to accomplish something like a chain of blocks. And don't forget: others (more important probably your future self) should still be able to read the code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use method references. The example below uses 'static' functions, the cool thing is that you can reference 'instance functions' as well (closures):

```
object Xxx {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        service("initial", ::toUpperCase, ::withSuffix)
    }

    fun toUpperCase(s: String) = s.toUpperCase()
    fun withSuffix(s: String) = "$s.mySuffix"

    fun service(argument: String, vararg enhancers: (String) -> String) {
        println(enhancers.fold(argument) { s, e -> e(s) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to return a function that take another function as argument to see if I can get two lambdas outside the `()`.

```
fun foo(m:String,bar1:(m:String)->Unit) : (bar2:(m:String)->Unit)->Unit
{
    bar1(m)
    return { bar2: (m: String) -> Unit -> bar2(m) }
}
```

Turns out I can't. I end up putting one more pair of `()` around or after the first function so that the compiler know the last lambda is an argument for the returned function instead of assume trying to pass two lambda expressions outside a parenthesized argument list.

```
(foo("a message"){println("message 1: $it")}){println("message 2: $it")}
```

or

```
foo("a message"){println("message 1: $it")}(){println("message 2: $it")}
```

Obviously these does not look any better. I think

```
foo("a message", { println("message 1: $it") }, { println("message 2: $it") } )
```

or

```
foo("a message", { println("message 1: $it") }){ println("message 2: $it")}
```

are good enough.

Interestingly this is allowed in Swift

```
func foo (m:String,bar1 : ((String) -> Void) ) -> (_:((String) -> Void))->Void
{
    bar1(m)
    return {bar2 in bar2(m)}
}
foo(m: "test"){print("m1: \($0)")}{print("m2: \($0)")}
```